# Using clCreateSubBuffer

Tags: opencl

I am trying to use create a subBuffer to read in a chunk of the buffer created from a 1-D vector. This is the code I am using:

```
d_treeArray = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(cl_uint)*total,NULL,&err);
cl_buffer_region region;
region.origin = 0; // This works
//region.origin = 4; // This doesnt work
region.size = 10*sizeof(cl_uint);
d_subtreeArray = clCreateSubBuffer(d_treeArray,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,CL_BUFFER_CREATE_TYPE_REGION, &region, &err);
if(err != CL_SUCCESS) {
      std::cout << "Cannot set buffers" << std::endl;
      exit(1);
}
```

Now when I give the region.origin as anything other than 0, I am getting -13 error (CL_INVALID_VALUE) which according to the help, means the region origin and size is out of bounds of the buffer. What might be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the error code -13 is for `CL_MISALIGNED_SUB_BUFFER_OFFSET`. Make sure the offset is aligned to the device's' `CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN`. The value is usually between 1024 and 4096.

Comment: Thank you. It was my mistake reading error codes. So if the offset is not aligned, there is no way we can create the subBuffer?

Comment: No, misaligned offset cannot be used to create sub-buffer nor can it be used for buffer operations. It may be possible to use offset when accessing buffer from the kernel if the algorithm allows for it. You may want to consider using certain (smaller) alignment to ensure optimal memory access.

Comment: Whats the meaning of offset not aligned? Lets say I have a object of size [66*46*46]. Now I want to subbuffer it into 66 objects of 46*46. Currently i am having the -13 error on my AMD card. This means my offset of N * 46 * 46 is not divisible by CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN? Also how do i check this value?