# How do I pass a device memory buffer with offset to my kernel

Tags: opencl

I have allocated a buffer on the device:

```
cl_mem buff;
```

I want to pass this buffer plus an offset to my kernel

i.e.
     buff + offset;

I find that this is not allowed. If I instead pass buff into my kernel and then 
calculate the offset buffer inside the kernel, then this is fine. But it adds a needless calculation to each kernel run.

So, I get that the device memory space is different than the host, so I can't do simple pointer arithmetic.  But, is there a way of taking an address to a device memory buffer,
calculating an offset, and passing this offset buffer into the kernel?

I think this may be possible with clCreateSubBuffer, but the offset needs to be aligned to the device's CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN, and this is not always possible for my kernel.

[Using clCreateSubBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575032/using-clcreatesubbuffer)

Comment: Do you think that a single *addition* like in `float *here = buff + 12;` has any noticable impact on performance?

Comment: Thanks, Marco. I don't know - probably as you imply, it does not. I am just trying to reduce needless calculations.

Comment: It will hardly be possible to see any difference here due to the *calculation*. You will rather see a difference because the memory accesses may then no longer be aligned properly (that is, they should be aligned with `CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN` for performance reasons)

Comment: Unaligned access penalty depends on hardware, so one can't be sure that misalign will impose any delays in IO operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If offset can be calculated statically, export macro, when building Program of your Kernel;
Assuming you are using C++

```
std::string macro;
std::stringstream ss;
// e. g. let it be 2^10
std::size_t offset = 1024;

ss << offset;
macro = "-D offset=";
macro += ss.str();

...
// When building Programm
clBuildProgram(..., macro.c_str(), ...);

//Inside your Kernel macro "offset" is defined
void __kenel my(
    __global const uchar* data)
{
    __global const uchar* data_with_shift = data + offset;
    return;
}
```

Though, calculations inside kernel are extreamly cheap, so **Marco13** gave you good advice.